# inner join postgresql - how can i make so "id" is the same in 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is my tables and i want to join them together with "testuser_id". how can i make so "testuser_id" is the same in adress as in testuser.

```
create table testuser ( 
    testuser_id serial,
    testuser_name varchar(100),
    testuser_number int,
    primary key(testuser_id)
)


create table adress( 
    adress_id serial,
    testuser_id int,
    adress_code int,
    street varchar(200),
    primary key(adress_id)
)

insert into testuser (testuser_name, testuser_number) values ('fnsnfsdfpi', 645645), ('fsdgfdg', 4634643)

insert into adress (adress_code, street) values (3453, 'gdfghdf'), (6463, 'gdgdgdg')
```

so when i run

```
select testuser.testuser_id ,testuser_name,testuser_number,adress_code,street 
from testuser INNER JOIN
     adress
     ON adress.testuser_id = testuser.testuser_id
```

i get one table and with the data i inserted in them

[image]

if someone gets what i am trying todo here plase help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I get the idea that you want to line up the tables somehow.  If so, you can use a CTE with an `insert` statement:

```
with tu as (
      insert into testuser (testuser_name, testuser_number)
          values ('fnsnfsdfpi', 645645), ('fsdgfdg', 4634643)
          returning *
    )
insert into adress (adress_code, street, testuser_id)
    select v.adress_code, v.street, tu.testuser_id
    from (select v.*, row_number() over () as seqnum
          from (values (3453, 'gdfghdf'),
                       (6463, 'gdgdgdg')
               ) v(adress_code, street)
         ) v join
         (select tu.*, row_number() over (order by testuser_id) as seqnum
          from tu
         ) tu
         on tu.seqnum = v.seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7577b75f39ae073510fc8973a0c67093) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: it works exactly how i want it, but im not quite sure i get it. is there a way to shorten it?. Gordon Linoff

Comment: @AdamElfsborg . . . There are tweaks that you can make, such as including the sequence number in the address in the innermost subquery.